# Sonarqube : Create a custom page using react

Tags: reactjs, sonarqube, custom-pages

I would like to create a custom page using react but I cannot find the documentation to do this. On the Sonarqube documentation, there only the way to create a custom page using javascript only and I don’t understand how the example plugin works with react.
Can you tell me if there is a documentation that I can use.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: There isn't. There is barely anyone (no one in fact, as far as I've seen) using custom pages currently.

However, it IS possible. You need to create a react project with [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) (or a similar JS packager).

I also recommend using [Create-React-App](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app). This fixes a lot of the setup for you. After that, in your `index.js` you use the example code from the SonarQube wiki.

Here is an example:

```
/*
    PRODUCTION ENTRYPOINT
 */
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Project from './components/Project';
import './main.css';

window.registerExtension('myplugin/coverage', function (options) {

    appendCustomCSS();
    let isDisplayed = true;

    window.SonarRequest.getJSON('/api/measures/component', {
        component: options.component.key,
        metricKeys: 'coverage'
    }).then(function (response) {
        if (isDisplayed) {
            let obj = JSON.parse(response.component.measures[0].value);
            let div = document.createElement('div');
            render(obj, div);
            options.el.appendChild(div);
        }
    });

    return function () {
        isDisplayed = false;
    };
});

function appendCustomCSS() {
    let fileref = document.createElement("link");
    fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
    fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
    fileref.setAttribute("href", "/static/myplugin/coverage.css");
    document.head.append(fileref);
}

function render(objectArray, container) {
    ReactDOM.render(<div className="Coverage"><Project objects={objectArray}/></div>, container);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. To create the custom page using react, I will use the example plugin (https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-custom-plugin-example). To do what I want, I just have to remove the unused scripts. The principle advantage is that I don't have to configure it, so I will not forget anything.